# What does this required empty parameter mean, when defining something?

Tags: latex

```
\newenvironment{nameOfEnvironment}[1][]%
```

Can someone explain the empty bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider reading [Is there a comprehensive and complete LaTeX reference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2124/5764) where you'll find information on all sorts of LaTeX2e sources.

Technically, `\newenvironment{<cmd>}[<num>][<default>]{<beg-def>}{<end-def>}` uses `\newcommand` as base, so understanding the latter will help you understand the former.

Specific to your case, [LaTeX2e for authors user guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/usrguide.pdf) mentions the following about `\newcommand`:

> ...the command:
>
> ```
> \newcommand{<cmd>}[<num>][<default>]{<definition>}
> ```
>
> defines `<cmd>` to be a command with `<num>` arguments, the first of which is
>   optional and has default value `<default>`.
>
> Note that there can only be one optional argument but, as before, there can be
>   up to nine arguments in total.

So,

```
\newenvironment{nameOfEnvironment}[1][]%
  {<beg-def>}
  {<end-def>}
```

defines an environment `nameOfEnvironment` that takes a single argument (as a result of `[1]`). This single argument is an optional argument (as a result of the second `[]`) that, if not specified, has an *empty* default value.

You would be able to use it as

```
\begin{nameOfEnvironment}
  <stuff>
\end{nameOfEnvironment}
```

or

```
\begin{nameOfEnvironment}[something]
  <stuff>
\end{nameOfEnvironment}
```

In the former case, the optional argument `#1` is empty, while the second has an optional argument value of `something`.

---

The following explanation is taken from [LaTeX: Structured documents for TeX (unofficial LaTeX reference manual)](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.pdf):

> #### 13.5 `\newenvironment` & `\renewenvironment`
>
> Synopses:
>
> ```
> \newenvironment[*]{env}[nargs][default]{begdef}{enddef}
> \renewenvironment[*]{env}[nargs]{begdef}{enddef}
> ```
>
> These commands define or redefine an environment `env`, that is, `\begin{env} ... \end{env}`.
>
> - `*`
>     The `*`-form of these commands requires that the arguments (not the contents
>     of the environment) not contain multiple paragraphs of text.
> - `env`
>     The name of the environment. For `\newenvironment`, `env` must not be
>     an existing environment, and the command `\env` must be undefined. For
>     `\renewenvironment`, `env` must be the name of an existing environment.
> - `nargs`
>     An integer from 1 to 9 denoting the number of arguments of the newly-defined
>     environment. The default is no arguments.
> - `default`
>     If this is specified, the first argument is optional, and default gives the default value for that argument.
> - `begdef`
>     The text expanded at every occurrence of `\begin{env}`; a construct of the form `#n` in `begdef` is replaced by the text of the `n`th argument.
> - `enddef`
>     The text expanded at every occurrence of `\end{env}`. It may not contain any
>     argument parameters.